# Copy a file and change the name

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I was asked to make a file copier that will change the name of a file, by adding "_Copy", but will keep the type of file.

For example:

```
c:\...mike.jpg
```

to:

```
c:\...mike_Copy.jpg
```

Here is my code:

```
private void btnChseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    prgrssBar.Minimum = 0;
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Title = "Which file do you want to copy ?";            

    DialogResult fc = ofd.ShowDialog();                       
    tbSource.Text = ofd.FileName;
    tbDestination.Text = tbSource.Text + "_Copy";          
}
```

Comment: What is the problem/error?

Comment: @Bas comeon it's obvious. 'it no work'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the classes `System.IO.FileInfo` and `System.IO.Path` to do what it appears you are attempting:

```
OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
if(od.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(od.FileName);
    string oldFile = fi.FullName;

    string newFile = oldFile.Replace(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oldFile), 
        string.Format("{0}_Copy", 
            System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oldFile)));
    MessageBox.Show(newFile);
}
```

Then you can call the following to perform the copy:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(oldFile, newFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the `_Copy` onto the end of the filename and not before the extension. You need to add it before the extension:

```
string destFileName = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName)}_Copy{Path.GetExtension(ofd.FileName)}";
```

Or without C# 6:

```
string destFileName = String.Format("{0}_Copy{1}",
                                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileName),
                                    Path.GetExtension(ofd.FileName));
```

Then to get the full path to the file use:

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName, destFileName));
```

Then to perform the actual copy just use:

```
File.Copy(ofd.FileName, fullPath);
```